# Querying a list item through UniqueId

Tags: rest, sharepoint, ms-office, office365, onedrive

I'm trying to get a list item through its Unique Id through REST API end point for list items.

### URL

https://{site-collection}/{personal-site}/_api/Web/Lists(guid'id')/items?$filter=UniqueId eq 'uniqueid'

But it isn't returning the item, instead it returns an empty list;

### Result

```
{
    "d": {
    "results": []
    }
}
```

When I make a similar query using **ItemId** or **GUID**, it works fine but for **UniqueId** I'm getting an empty list. Is this even possible? If not then why have a **UniqueId**, can't **GUID/ItemId** suffice? One possible explanation could be that it is the **UniqueId** that is referenced in other lists not **GUID** or **ItemID**.
So why can't I filter an item with **UniqueId**?

Comment: If you try to filter a lookup list see this [article](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Applying-Filters-to-Lookup-Fields-with-the-SP2013-REST-API)

Comment: You ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue? did u try UniqueId eq guid 'xxx-xxx-xx-xx'?

Comment: Nope, no luck with this. Plus the horrific level of support they provide...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes stumbling upon this thread, then the answer is
_api/Web/Lists('GUID')/GetItemByUniqueId('GUID')

:)

Comment: must be recent. could you please share the documentation link for this?

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan, the thing is there is no documentation on MSDN - but I have validated it against 2013, 2019 and SPO (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531433(v=office.15))